Accidentally ran mkswap on ext4 fs
I accidentally used mkswap on a unmounted 2 TB data partition of a hard drive (not an SSD), while I was on a live USB session. I did not run swapon as I immediately realized what I had just done.
I wonder if there is any way to fix this maybe through the use of e2fsck.
I ran mke2fs -n on the affected partition without any other arguments and got a bunch of backup superblocks. However when I run dumpe2fs -o superblocks=N I get confusing information, like the Last write time is August 2023 (but I had been using this until Sept. 2 2024).
Perhaps because I haven't used the exact same arguments as when creating the FS the backup superblocks I found are from an older filesystem or I am missunderstanding something about the dump.
If there are other superblocks, how would I find them?
Or could I use this superblocks anyway to try and run e2fsck on the file system?

Just checking... (1) you accidentally ran mkswap /dev/sdX (2) you then ran mke2fs -n /dev/sdX. In both cases device sdX is your unmounted SD card. Is that right?

https://www.r-studio.com/free-linux-recovery/

mkswap only wipes the first 4096 bytes. If nothing else happened, e2fsck might succeed as is. To test it, make a full copy (or snapshot or other copy-on-write overlay).

Also consider wipefs -a -t swap so this swap partition is not auto activated on accident. That's when discard happens and all data is gone. Also disable fstrim, stick to readonly with mount -o loop,ro.

@ChrisDavies That is mostly correct, but my drive is a SATA hard drive connected to my motherboard. Edited my question to add some clarity, I hope.

@frostschutz I did wipefs -a -t swap and now I'm running e2fsck -n -E fixes_only.

@frostschutz Did a second run of e2fsck -E fixes_only (no -n this time) and this did it. You may want to add an answer so I can accept it.
